# React-bootstrap Popover arrow colors are inverted when arrow is vertical vs. horizontal

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-5

I have a react-bootstrap Popover component with custom styling for the arrow (gray color and 50% opacity). The CSS is as follows:

```
.popover .popover-arrow::before, .popover .popover-arrow::after {
  border-color: #212529 !important;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-top-color: transparent !important;
  border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
}
```

This works fine for horizontal arrows (when the Popover is left or right of the target):

[image: Horizontal arrows are styled correctly, gray with 50% opacity]

However, when the arrow is vertical (Popover above or below the target), the colors are inverted to give a transparent arrow on a grey background:

[image: Vertical arrows are inverted, transparent on a gray 50% opaque background]

My question is, why does this inversion happen and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I managed to fix this with the following CSS:

```
.popover .popover-arrow {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.75;
}

.popover[x-placement^=top]>.popover-arrow:after {
    border-top-color: #212529;
}

.popover[x-placement^=bottom]>.popover-arrow:after {
    border-bottom-color: #212529;
}

.popover[x-placement^=right]>.popover-arrow:after {
    border-right-color: #212529;
}

.popover[x-placement^=left]>.popover-arrow:after {
    border-left-color: #212529;
}
```

Thanks to Michal Duszak for [this snippet](https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/standard/m-duszak/3687499#css-tab-view) which gave me something to go on.